# If f is n-times differentiable, and $f^n$ is never 0, then f has at most n zeros in R

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, roots

Let $n \ge 0$, let $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be n-times differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$, and assume that $f^{(n)}(x) \neq 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Show that $f$ has at most $n$ zeros in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: rolle's theorem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that, if $f^{(n)}$ is never zero, $f^{(n-1)}$ is either always decreasing or increasing, thus it must have at most one zero (Mean Value Theorem).
Now, you have two cases: $f^{(n-1)}$ has one zero, or it doesn't have any (think $f(x) = e^x$). Thus, we see that there are three cases for $f^{(n-2)}$.  Do you see why? Can you use this idea in order to prove this statement by induction? 
Hint: take $g(x) = f'(x)$ and use the induction hypothesis.

Comment: So the three cases for $f^{(n-2)}$ are one zero, two zeros, or none?

Comment: Precisely!  Remember that you need to prove that $f$ has *at most* n zeroes, not that it has n zeroes.